# Why file version obtained from .Net and file version in windows explorer is different?

Tags: c#, windows, file, powershell, version

We have installed OPC redistributable which is open source software. The file version of one of the file in it shown in explorer as 1.10.101.0

But when i see the version using Powershell (and also in C# utility) , the version is showing as 1.10.100.0

[image]

Why it is showing like this? I have verified with many other files which has similar version. There also this round-off error occurs. Why does it behave like this? We have to verify the installed version of file programmatically via dot net . This difference is making it as error.

[image]

Comment: Maybe because of behavior described in this article: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2014/12/07/how-to-correctly-check-file-versions-with-powershell/